# How to add disable-site-isolation-trials to electron?

Tags: node.js, electron, chromium

I need to set *disable-site-isolation-trials* on an electron app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running this before app.on('ready') worked for me : app.commandLine.appendArgument("--disable-site-isolation-trials")